# List matching values of different arrays with separate key location

Tags: underscore.js

Given the below data, how would I go about finding things that are liked by more than one person with an output of:

{
 liked: 'bananas',
 likedBy: ['person1', 'person2']
}

```
var data = [
  {
    name: 'person1',
    likes: ['bananas', 'apples']
  },
  {
    name: 'person2',
    likes' ['grapes', 'bananas']
  }
]
```

Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an external variable and nested foreach loops, sure there are more efficient ways but this is fairly succinct and easy to read

```
var likes = {};
_.each(data,function(person){
   _.each(person.likes,function(like){

        if(!likes[like]) 
           likes[like]=[];

        likes[ like ].push( person.name );
   })
}
```

you can then filter out the values that don't have more than one element

```
likes = _.filter(likes,function(value,name){ return value.length > 1; });
```

which would give you

```
{ 'bananas':['person1','person2'] }
```

in the case you provided

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the data and create a hashmap that has `likes` items as keys, and an array of `names` as values.

```
count = {}
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < data['likes'].length; j++){
        var key = data[i]['likes'][j]
        if(!(key in count)){
            count[key] = []
        }
        count[key].push(data[i]['name'])
    }
}
```

Example output is something like this:

```
{'bananas':['person1', 'person2'], 'apples':['person1'], 'grapes':['person2']}
```

Comment: I like this answer the best but probably shouldn't accept it because it doesn't use underscore

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses more underscore than you can shake a stick at but is not as efficient as the plain old javascript answers.

```
// get a list of all the fruits
var fruits = _.chain(data)
    .pluck('likes')
    .flatten()
    .uniq()
    .value();

var results = _.map(fruits, function(fruit){

    var peopleWhoLikeThisFruit = _.filter(data, function(person){
        return _.contains(person.likes, fruit);
    });

    return {
        liked: fruit,
        likes: _.pluck(peopleWhoLikeThisFruit, 'name')
    }
});
```